# jQuery document.ready vs pageLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've picked up an existing project from another developer and ive noticed in the code that they are executing js code within three different event handlers...

```
function pageLoad() {
//execute code
}

$(document).ready(function() {
//execute code
});

$(function() {
//execute code
});
```

My question is - arent they all exactly the same? Or at least the last two? I understand that pageLoad is called by the .NET framework so it's not dependent on the jQuery library having loaded like the second two are - that's my understanding anyway - is that about correct?

Comment: The last two are exactly the same. As for the difference between `pageLoad` and the jQuery ready handler, I found the following article; http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: The 2. and 3. functions execute on the `DOMContentLoaded` event (DOM-ready), the 1. function is just a declaration.

Answer (score 20):

**$(document).ready()**

- Ideal for one time initialization.
- Optimization black magic; may run slightly earlier than pageLoad().
- Does not re-attach functionality to elements affected by partial postbacks.

**pageLoad()**

- Unsuitable for one time initialization if used with UpdatePanels.
- Slightly less optimized in some browsers, but consistent.
- Perfect for re-attaching functionality to elements within UpdatePanels.

Answer (score 5):

`pageLoad` and the jQuery `ready` handler are both methods of accomplishing similar things.

The second two examples are identical.

http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: It's worth pointing out something from the posted link: The `pageLoad` function could be executed more than once while the `DomContentLoaded` event which jQuery uses would not.

Answer (score 3):

The last one is just a shorthand notation of the one above it. http://www.jquery4u.com/dom-modification/types-document-ready/

Comment: Top is a custom function looks like

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` will not fire for the partial postbacks (happened from AJAX). In that case, you should use `MS AJAX` pageLoad function when you need to execute something when the page loads either from the full postback or partial.

The article given in the Encosia site is a good read.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
`enter code here`
//execute code
});

$(function() {
`enter code here`
});
```

Both functions perform task in  the same way, executes code inside them once the document is ready.

```
function pageLoad() {
`enter code here`
}
```

This executes after every post back, generally used with update panels controls as the above two functions does not execute every time or every post back.

Answer (score -2):

In this site you will find the difference :)

[Document.ready Vs pageLoad](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)