# Knockout not validating visible check after startup

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an index.html page that holds my whole front-end webapp. It imports a javascript file with various functions and displays data from the index.html page based on function calls.

I have a database call and then some paging - the paging is my problem. I have these 2 buttons in my index.html file:

```
  <li style="margin-left: 650px">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: myApp.vm.previous, visible: previousEnabled()">Previous
     </button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: myApp.vm.next, visible: nextEnabled()">Next
     </button>
  </li>
```

This is the previousEnabled and nextEnabled functions in the javascript file:

```
  previousEnabled = ko.computed(function(){
    console.log("previousEnabled check --------------------");
    return _currentPage > 1;
  });

  nextEnabled = ko.computed(function(){
    console.log("nextEnabled check --------------------");
    return _currentPage < totalPage;
  });
```

I only see previousEnabled check and nextEnabled check logging when I log into the front-end . I don't see it ever again when I got records from the database and want to page through them. It seems like my visible validation only happens once and then never again. Why is this?

Comment: Seems your'e using ajax & js is not working after postbacks. Where do you put these scripts ? like onLoad or document.ready ?

Comment: Its in Document ready

Comment: `document.ready` doesn't run after postbacks. Try putting code in `function pageLoad()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both _currentPage and totalPage variables are observables, then you do not need to invoke the functions in your visible bindings because they are computed observables; knockout will know what to do. Try removing the brackets from the binding, e.g. use `data-bind="click: myApp.vm.previous, visible: previousEnabled"` as the binding.

Currently you are not passing an observable object to the visible binding but the output from calling that function (which is not observable and won't know when to update). Have a look at the [knockout documentation for computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

Also that is a strange click binding you have. Usually I would expect to see something like `data-bind="click: previous"`. If in doubt have a look at the documentation (I certainly do).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem is my _currentPage variable was not observable!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your'e using ajax & js is not working after postbacks.

`document.ready` doesn't run after postbacks. Try putting code in `function pageLoad()` like:

```
function pageLoad()
{
 //....
 previousEnabled = ko.computed(function(){
    console.log("previousEnabled check --------------------");
    return _currentPage > 1;
  });

  nextEnabled = ko.computed(function(){
    console.log("nextEnabled check --------------------");
    return _currentPage < totalPage;
  });
  //....
}
```

For details refer:[jQuery document.ready vs pageLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824069/jquery-document-ready-vs-pageload)

Comment: You are right yes ajax & js. I don't have a pageLoad() function?

Comment: I didn't get `I don't have a pageLoad() function`, you tried using `pageLoad()` & it doesn't work OR you don't know how to use?? Its native js function & by default works in all browsers.